# How to set content type for JSON API in Rails 5 API only app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Follow the specification to use the JSON api, the content type must be set to `application/vnd.api+json`; however, setting the `ContentType` in every action in the controller seems tedious (see code below).

```
  def foo
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.api+json'
    # ...
  end
```

Is there a better way to achive the same result? Since this is an API only app is this possible to set content type at application level?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `before_action` directive:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :set_headers

  def set_headers
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.api+json'
  end

end
```